# Which of these sentences would you prefer? Are all of them grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

I know as much about video games as **you know about** chemistry.

I know as much about video games as you **do about** chemistry.

I know as much about video games as you **do** chemistry.

Are all three sentences grammatically correct? As a non-native speaker, I find the 3rd sentence a bit odd. I don't think it's grammatically incorrect, but I'd prefer the second sentence to this one. Which of these sentences would you prefer?

Answer (score 1):

It's more a question of whether they are idiomatic than whether they are grammatically correct. I find the second more natural than the first. The third doesn't really work; it makes **do** stand in for too many words.